# Updating key in NSMutableDictionary

Tags: objective-c, nsmutabledictionary

`json` is a NSMutableDictionary with a key "message". I need to "clean" the data in that key using `stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString`

`NSLog(@"json: %@", json);` outputs this:

```
json: {
    conversationId = 61;
    countmessagesinconversation = 2;
    message = "Messages exist!";
    messagesinconversation =     (
                {
            message = "Hi";
            messagecreated = "June 24, 2013 16:16";
            messageid = 68;
            sentby = Thomas;
            sentbyID = 1;
            title = "Subject";
        },

                {
            message = "What's &nbsp;up?";
            messagecreated = "September 22, 2013 17:00";
            messageid = 331;
            sentby = Steve;
            sentbyID = 2;
            title = "Subject";
        }
    );
    success = 1;
}
```

So, this is what I've come up with, but I'm clearly getting it all wrong.

```
NSString *newstr = [[NSString alloc]init];

    for (newstr in [[[json objectForKey:@"messagesinconversation"]allKeys]copy]){
        newstr = [newstr stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"&nbsp;"
                                             withString:@""];
        [json setValue:newstr forKey:@"message"];
    }
```

Could somebody please help me out with this and explain so I understand the concept? I know how to do this with an array but what my problem is (I think) is that I do not fully understand how to access the right key in the dictionary.

Edit: Sorry for not being clear in my question. What happens is that if there are two space characters in the key `message` then `"&nbsp;"` shows up when I display it on the screen.

Comment: At first a side not, not really related to your issue. There is no need to alloc/init newstr. You are just wasting resources.

Comment: @Hermann Could you elaborate on that?

Comment: I tried an answer but deleted it again because I misuderstood some detail. Well, regarding the "elaboration", ... You create a string variable and then you allocate space for it and then you initialize it. Meaning you created an instance of NSString. Next is you use it in the for loop as the "counter variable". You assign a value to it. By doing so the newly allocated and intialized instance is abandoned. In the event that you do not ARC you would even crate a memory leak here. But again, that is not your real problem.

Comment: I changed and undeleted the answer, although it is not really an answer. Pleae provide more details. 1) Which message do you attempt to change? The message object of the inner dictionaries or the outer one? 2) There is no %nbsp at all in your data. What are you tring to do really? 3) Don't you get an exeption thrown on runtime? If so then always provide the error message along with your question.

Comment: I edited my question... It's the inner one. (It is unfortunate that there is an inner and an outer key with the same name.) The code I came up by myself gives me the following error: `*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFArray allKeys]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7a7dcd0'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
//First get the array of message dictionaries:
NSArray * messages = [json objectForKey:@"messagesinconversation"];

//create new array for new messages
NSMutableArray * newMessages = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:messages.count];

//then iterate over all messages (they seem to be dictionaries)
for (NSDictionary * dict in messages)
{
    //create new mutable dictionary
    NSMutableDictionary * replacementDict = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary:dict];

    //get the original text
    NSString * msg = [dict objectForKey:@"message"];

    //replace it as you see fit
    [replacementDict setObject:[msg stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"&nbsp;" withString:@""] forKey:@"message"];

    //store the new dict in new array
    [newMessages addObject:replacementDict];
}

//you are done - replace the messages in the original json dict
[json setObject:newMessages forKey:@"messagesinconversation"];
```

Comment: Thanx a lot. I got this working with the desirable effect and `replacementDict` is stripped of the characters. But could you please help me to actually get the data into the original dictionary `json`?

Comment: If the json is indeed mutable, then just add [json setObject:replacementDict forKey:@"messagesinconversation"];

Comment: Actually, it was not mutable, but I fixed that. Anyway, what worked was `[json setObject:newMessages forKey:@"messagesinconversation"];` Thank you for all your help.

Answer (score 0):

Now that the requirements are more clear I'll try an answer. I try to use the same names as in your question and suggested in erlier answers.

Make `json` an `NSMUtableDictionary` where you declare it. Then go forward:

```
json = [json mutableCopy]; // creates a mutable dictionary based on json which is immutable as result of the json serialization although declared as mutable. 

NSMutableArray *msgArray = [[json objectForKey:@"messagesinconversation"] mutableCopy];  //this fetches the array from the dictinary and creates a mutable copy of it. 
[json setValue:newstr forKey:@"messagesinconversation"];  // replace the original immutable with the mutable copy. 

for (int i = 0; i < [msgArray count]; i++) {
    NSMutableDictionary mutableInnerDict = [[msgArray objectAtIndex:i] mutableCopy]; // fetching the i-th element and replace it by a mutable copy of the dictionary within. 
    [msgArray replaceObjectAtIndex:i withObject:mutableInnerDict]; // it is now mutable and replaced within the array. 
    NSString *newString = [[[msgArray objectAtindex:i] objectForKey:@"message"]  stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"&nbsp;" withString:@" "];  // crates a new string with all &nbsp removed with blanks. 
    [mutableInnerDict setValue:newString forKey:@"message"];
}
```

Regarding the replacement of &nbsp with " ", is this really what you want? I am asking because &nbsp does not occur in your sample data. Or do you want to remove blanks at all?

Answer (score 0):

Add your array of dictionary in another mutable array

```
NSMutableArray *msgArray = [[json objectForKey:@"messagesinconversation"] mutableCopy];
```

Use `for loop` for access it.

```
for (int i = 0 ; i < msgArray.count ; i++)
{
     [[[msgArray objectAtindex:i] objectForKey:@"message"]  stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"&nbsp;" withString:@""];
}

[self.mainJSONDic setValue:msgArray forKey:@"messagesinconversation"];
```

Try this code might helpful in your case:

Comment: And do the "cleaning" inside the `for loop`?

Comment: @Thomas - what >> ?  i'm not getting you.

Comment: The purpose of this is to remove instances of "&nbsp;" in `messages`. I'm trying to use `stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"&nbsp;"
                                             withString:@""`

Comment: @Thomas - then you does not need to write such like `@"&nbsp;"` just write `" "` and check it now.

Comment: That certainly leads the right way. Although the objects within the msgArray will not be mutable. Which means that `setValue` should throw an exception. However, you too create an empty instance of NSMutableArray and throw it away in the very next statement. Just initalize it with nil or don't initalize it at all or directly assign the mutableCopy to it.

Comment: @HermannKlecker i convert msgArray to mutableCopy so it doesnt generate any error :)

Comment: I get `'-[__NSCFDictionary setObject:forKey:]: mutating method sent to immutable object'`

Comment: this error is said that we replace string of immutable dictionary you need to do mutableCopy of your message dictionary.. nd your problem will solve :)

Comment: @iPatel, I am surprised. Does the mutability cascade through to the dictionaies within the array? AFAIK `stringByReplacing...` creates a new string instances which it returns and which you ignore while the original string remains unchanged. It is a method of `NSString`, not `NSMutableString`.